# How to pass variable in url_for flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

in place of `newyork` I want to pass `form.city.data` which is a input from form by the user.

```
    <div>
        <iframe height="800" width="100%" class="p-5 embed-responsive-item"
            src="{{ url_for('static',filename='videos/newyork.html') }}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try this way

```
{% set path = url_for('static',filename='videos/' + form.city.data + '.html') %}
<div>
    <iframe height="800" width="100%" class="p-5 embed-responsive-item"
        src="{{ path }}" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```